# Device Orientation not working firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, device-orientation

Anyone know why the device orientation detection is not working in Mozilla Firefox? And no I'm not using mozOrientation.It works just fine in Chrome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Which platform are you testing on?  There are some platforms where Gecko fires devicemotion events but not deviceorientation events (because the platform provides motion information, but not orientation information)...

Comment: I've [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb5f8/4/) to include devicemotion, but nothing's firing for me either.  (Firefox Nightly 30.0a1, OS X 10.9.2)

Comment: Still not firing.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093857/device-orientation-api-returns-different-values-for-desktop-browsers